# Artifact dependency paths must be specified twice?

Tags: teamcity

I'm new to TeamCity, so maybe I'm not getting something here, but when I set up a configuration I specify the paths to its artifacts. When I set up a second configuaration that depends on the first, I have to specify the artifact paths again in the Artifact Dependency (see picture). Why is that? Or am I missing something?  Here's an annotated screen capture: [image: Annotated screen capture of the Artifact Dependency window]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The artifact paths line allows you to select from multiple artifacts, or drill down into particular artifacts from the build you've specified in the "Depend On" field.  For example, we have builds that output multiple artifacts.  We then have builds that are dependent on them that use one particular artifact.  It can be a weird duplication of data.  We've gotten around that somewhat by specifying the artifact to publish as a build parameter(like %"SetupArtifact%") and then you can refer to that in the build using the artifact as "%dep..SetupArtifact%" where  is the build type ID of the build you're using artifacts from.